# Как забрать данные из формы в модальном окне bootstrap с помощью ajax jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap

Допустим у меня создаются в цикле несколько модальных окон bootstrap, где главный div окна:

```
<div id="myModal'.$rezult['id'].'" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

Форма в окне:

```
<form id="form'.$rezult['id'].'" action="ajax/insert.php?id='.$rezult['id'].'" method="post">
```

Кнопка вызова окна:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal'.$rezult['id'].'">Insert</button>
```

Далее в модальном окне расположил 2 кнопки `<input>` и `<button>`, обе кнопки имеют возможность закрывать окно:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" value="Сохранить" form="form'.$rezult['id'].'">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Отменить</button>
```

для отправки данных с формы я использовал `ajaxform plugin`, но атрибут `type="sumbit"` не срабатывает из-за атрибута `data-dismiss="modal"` и в итоге скрипт не срабатывает. Не зная точного называния `id` формы и главного `div'a`, я не знаю как мне забрать данные.

jquery скрипт:

```
$(this).ajaxForm(
{
    success: function(data)
    {
        if(data)
        {
            $('#pkSkLapa').html(data);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("error!");
        }
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал эту идею по другому.
Теперь модальное окно создается единожды, тобишь не в цикле:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

Только кнопка вызова окна осталась в цикле, они вызывают одно и тоже окно, однако теперь имеют атрибут `value`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg getid" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="'.$rezult['id'].'">Insert</button>
```

Изменил `<input type="submit">` и добавил одни `<input type="hidden">`:

```
<button id="post" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="form1">Сохранить</button>
<input id="btnsubmit" type="hidden" name="id" value="ok" form="form1" >
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Отменить</button>
```

И далее делаю так:

```
function getByid()
{
    var getid=$(this).val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        data: "getid="+getid, //отправляю id в глоб.массив $_POST['id']
        url: "ajax/getbyid.php?ref=pk9kl",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data!=null)
            {
                if(data.e)//если пришла ошибка
                {
                    $("#vu").val(data.e);
                    $("#skola").val(data.e);
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#vu").val(data.vu);
                    $("#skola").val(data.skola);
                    $("#btnsubmit").attr("value", data.id);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $("#vu").val("error!");
                $("#skola").val("error!");
            }
        }
    });
}
$('#form1').ajaxForm(
{
    success: function(data)
        {
            $("#myModal").modal('hide');//закрываем окно
            $("#form1")[0].reset();// ресет формы
            location.reload();//перезагрузка страницы
        }       
});
```

Правда так и не смог добиться асинхронного обновления, поэтому решил просто перезагружать страницу, выглядит тоже не плохо и в глазах не рябит.

Answer (score 0):

Уберите `data-dismiss="modal"` и добавьте:

```
$(this).ajaxForm(
{
    var modal = $(this).closest('.modal');
    success: function(data)
    {
        modal.modal('hide'); // либо сюда
        if(data)
        {
            $('#pkSkLapa').html(data);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("error!");
        }
    }       
});

$('input[type="submit"]', this).click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.modal').modal('hide'); // либо сюда
});
```

Comment: Первый способ не вызывается вовсе, а второй скрывает окно, но не убирает полупрозрачный серый фон. Элемент #pkSkLapa так же не обновляется, хотя через Firebug я вижу что запрос был отправлен и ответ с сервера пришёл.

Comment: Обновила ответ, на счет #pkSkLapa ничего сказать не могу, это уже отдельный вопрос.